# How to change the values in a specific row of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have problem to change value matrix in specific "depth"

```
R = 6;
C = 12;
depth = 6

for j=1:depth;
    result(:,:,j)=randint(R,C,[0 2])
    for i=1:R,
        A(i,:,j)=randperm(C);
    end
end
```

this following code that i have used currently
but this code only still work from 1th depth. then, I wish that my code would be work from 3th depth (h=3:depth).

```
for h=3:depth;       
    idx = bitand(A(:,:,h)>= 1, A(:,:,h)<= 4); 
    result([false(size(idx,1),1) idx(:,1:end-1)]) = 3
    result(idx)=1
end
```

anyone have suggestion to improve that code??

Comment: are you asking how one can generally change the values of a single row, or are you asking for help with this exact algorithm?

Comment: yeah, I asked about right code to do like what i want to do. i want use above code in order to work from h=3:depth (not h=1:depth)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say the posted code doesn't work. I've run it on my machine and it executes without any errors.

Comment: We'll be better able to help you if you describe what you are trying to accomplish with the code rather than just posting code that "doesn't work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is quite vague. If all you want to know is how 3D indexing is working, you can
play around with the following code:

```
%# Construct A and result.
result = rand(R, C, depth);
A = 10 * rand(R, C, depth);

idx = (A >= 1) & (A <= 3);
result([false(size(A, 1), 1, size(A, 3)) idx(:,1:end-1,:)]) = 1; %# or 3??
```